# is Valid to Check and Push to another URL within Constructor of React Component?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I created ACL based routing application, Which means some user have authorisation to view pages and some other don't have. In run-time Authorised user can change privileged  to unauthorised user to access pages.

Example : Initially Checker don't have permission to access page, but when admin allows the page  access in run-time, checker can access that page. I will change navbar access according to the user-permission.

Is that valid to check privilege within the constructor and push to desired page.

```
class SomeComponent extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      ...some values
    }

    const user_data = localStorage.getItem('userData') // user data getting while login
    if(user_data.isAdmin === false || user_data.checker === false){
       this.props.history.push('/noauth');
    }
  }
}
```

Is that valid to push to another component without anything to render. If it is invalid, this will leads to performance or unpredictable issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Ideally this check needs to be done at the level of Router. Something like this

```
const isAuthenticated = () => {
  const user_data = localStorage.getItem('userData');
  if (user_data.isAdmin === false || user_data.checker === false) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
};

const AuthenticatedRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) => {
        return isAuthenticated() ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/noauth" />;
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

Here isAuthenticated function returns where the User is authenticated or not. You can check the localStorage value in isAuthenticated and return.

Comment: Yes, your approach is correct, even though authorised user can change permission of the unauthorised user via other system, So that, I'm checking permission at each component mount. In Some case I need to check in constructor itself, for not visible rendered html from that component. So I'm asking, Is ideal to redirect to another component in constructor itself ?